# How to get tags when using publish_post

Tags: posts, categories, tags

I need to get tags from new posts as they get created. Problem is, with my current code, the tags can't be grabbed when using ***publish_post*** as the hook upon post creation, as ***publish_post*** fires **BEFORE** the tags are saved into the database. My current code essentially works after a post is saved a second time, which isn't ideal.

I've tried using "***save_post***", but it does not work when a post is created, but only when an existing post is saved.

Is there a way around this? I even tried digging for a way to trigger a save/update event after initial post creation, but that hasn't faired too well either.
(if I'm missing any details, please let me know)

Please see my code below:

```
<?php

function add_category_based_on_title( $post_id ) {

    
    // tags
    $tags_raw = get_the_tags( $post_id );
    $tags_map = array_map(function($tags_raw) { return $tags_raw->name; },$tags_raw);

    $tags = implode(" ", $tags_map );
    
        
    //-----
    
    // get category id - Anime Manga
    $category_id_am = get_cat_ID( 'Anime & Manga' ); 
    
    // keywords to check for - Anime Manga
    $keywords_am = array("anime","manga","anime & manga","anime and manga");

    // check criteria, add to category - Anime Manga
    foreach ($keywords_am as $arraycheck) {
        if (stripos($tags, $arraycheck) !== FALSE) {

            // set category
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, [ $category_id_am ], true );

        }
    }
    
    //-----
    
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'add_category_based_on_title' );
```

Comment: Are you using Gutenberg (the block editor) and WordPress 5.7+?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yup, that's correct. Though I'm using a plugin to automatically create the posts, so I'm not sure if Gutenberg or Classic plays a factor.

Comment: Sorry! I misread :p (I didn't really pay attention to the "I'm using a plugin to automatically create the posts" in your comment) and therefore, I deleted my answer. But like you've confirmed it yourself, the `wp_after_insert_post` hook I suggested is indeed a (core) hook that would let you access the post tags regardless on initial creation or subsequent updates/saves; but since it didn't work with the plugin, then you're gonna need to contact the plugin author and ask them about the right hook to use. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Sally. Appreciate it.